# Access Adapter of Recyclerview from Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, adapter, android-recyclerview

i have a fragment layout with a recycler view. In the fragment activity i have a method that calls a method from the adapter:

in the fragment activity:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scrollview_quran, container, false);

        FragmentActivity c=getActivity();

        HolyQuranActivity dquran = (HolyQuranActivity)getActivity();

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        // 3. create an adapter

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        mAdapter = new QuranAdapter(dquran.tweets, dquran,dquran);

        // 4. set adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // 5. set item animator to DefaultAnimator
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

      recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {


                // item clicked

            }
        });
```

// Here is the method that calls the adapter
    public void test(){

```
        mAdapter.test2();

    }
```

And then in the adapter i call the method test2, that just calls:

```
public void test2()
    {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

But when i run this i get a null object reference error.....
Where is my error?

thats the error message:

Process: com.stegreifapps.islamichub, PID: 486
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.stegreifapps.islamichub.QuranAdapter.test()' on a null object reference
            at com.stegreifapps.islamichub.Holy_Quran_Fragment.test(Holy_Quran_Fragment.java:150)

Comment: Where do you call test2 in fragment?